# how to retrieve current path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

hello i'm new to react and react router i have exercice page contain multiple exercices so when i click an exrcice i can get individual exercice

```
 <Link to={`exercice/${item.id}`} exact path={`exercice/${item.id}`} className={MenuCard.menu}>
```

with path like this

```
 http://localhost:3000/exercice/0002
```

and  i have pricing page wich contain exerice component so when i click an exercice from pricing page i get

```
http://localhost:3000/pricing/exercice/0002
```

wich goes to nothing
how i can get

http://localhost:3000/exercice/0002
thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "retrieve current path". Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what the issue is and provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: i want to get individual exercice from pricing page wich contain exercice component i get path like this http://localhost:3000/pricing/exercice/0002  i want to get http://localhost:3000/exercice/0002 without "pricing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `/` at the beginning of your paths so the links are not relative to the current route. As stated in [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#link):

> A relative `<Link to>` value (that does not begin with `/`) resolves relative to the parent route, which means that it builds upon the URL path that was matched by the route that rendered that `<Link>`.